# asociar imagen a pagina WP con PHP

Tags: wordpress-imagenes

quiero asociar una imagen a una pagina/entrad WP con la funcion PHP *set_post_thumbnail()*

Este es el codigo que uilizo:

```
require_once('wp-includes/post.php');
set_post_thumbnail( $_GET['page'],$_GET['img']);
```

donde page e img son los parametros recividos (de un formulario, por ejemplo)

Sin embargo, obtengo el siguiente error que no se como solucionar:
**Fatal error:** Class 'WP_Post' not found in .../wp-includes/post.php on line 546, ¿alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

¿¿Se puede **asociar una misma imagen(un solo ID) a distintas paginas**???

En el panel de administracion de WP solo te deja elegir una pagina a la que asociar la imagen pero si modifico la tabla wp_posts(con SQL) y actualizo el ID en el campo post_parent(la pagina a la que asocio la imagen) me conserva la imagen en los ID(páginas) anteriores

Gracias:D a todos, saludos

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error es claro:

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Post' not found in .../wp-includes/post.php on
>   line 546

Al parecer la clase `WP_Post` no se está incluyendo o no existe.

Debes verificar lo siguiente:

1. Que en el archivo `wp-setting.php` (ubicado por lo general en `public_html`) estás incluyendo la clase. Allí tienes que encontrar esta línea, sin que la misma esté comentada, por supuesto:

   ```
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-post.php' );
   ```
2. Verificar que en el directorio `public_html/wp-includes` existe un archivo llamado **`class-wp-post.php`**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @A. Cedano, he verificado que **ambos puntos se cumplen** ¿Otra posible causa del error?

Comment: @fede el mensaje de error es muy claro, dice que no está encontrando la clase `WP_Post`. Si dices que tienes lo indicado en los puntos 1 y 2, entonces puede ser que tu WP esté apuntando a directorios equivocados. ¿En el archivo `wp-config.php` tienes algo parecido a esto?: `/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: @fede Para verificar que tu WP está apuntando al directorio correcto pon esto al final del mismo `wp-config.php`: **`echo ABSPATH;`** Luego abre cualquier página de tu sitio y verifica la ruta que se imprimirá al principio y comprueba si coincide con la ruta donde deben estar los archivos antes mencionados.

Comment: @A.Celdano tengo la **definicion de ABSPATH en mi wp-config.php** y al poner un **echo al final del archivo wp-config.php** se imprime la ruta correcta a mi directorio raiz de WP

Comment: Ok @fede, no olvides borrar ese `echo` del `wp-config.php`. Para seguir depurando pon esto, no sea que el directorio include no esté definido: `echo WPINC;` y di lo que imprime. También, en el código que indicas en tu pregunta,  depura las variables antes de llamar a `set_post_thumbnail`: `var_dump($_GET['page']);` y también   `var_dump($_GET['img']);`... Por cierto ¿ese código seguro que lo usas dentro de Wordpress? ¿Dónde lo usas específicamente?

Comment: @A.Celdano utilice otro echo con la constante WPINC que me muestra el valor correcto "wp-includes"

respecto a las variables $_GET[] las sustitui ppor los IDs numericos del la imagen y pagina, respectivamente(para depurar problemas) 
pero me devuelve el mismo error. no entiendo por que no encuentra la clase WP_Post:(

Comment: @fede es muy extraño. Puede ser un error debido al **contexto** en el que intentas implementar tu código.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74451/discussion-between-fede-and-a-cedano).